# Passing large data structures to unmanaged code using fixed pointer

Tags: c#, c++, interop

I'm developing an application which consists of two parts:

1. C# front-end
2. C++ number cruncher

In some cases the amount of data passed from C# to C++ can be really large. I'm talking about Gb and maybe more. There's a large array of doubles in particular and I wanted to pass a pinning/fixed pointer to this array to C++ code. The number crunching can take up to several hours to finish. I'm worrying about any problems that can be triggered by this usage of pinning pointers. As I see it, the garbage collector will not be able to touch this large memory region for a long time. Can this cause any problems? Should I consider a different strategy?

I thought that instead of passing the whole array I could provide an interface for building this array from within C++ code, so that the memory is owned by unmanaged part of the application. But in the end both strategies will create a large chunk of memory which is not relocatable for C# garbage collector for a long time. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have a problem.  Large arrays are allocated in the Large Object Heap.  Pinning them can not have any detrimental effect, the LOH is not compacted.  "Large" here means an array of doubles with 1000 or more elements for 32-bit code or any array equal or larger than 85,000 bytes.

Comment: Having multiple allocations in the LOH up to a GB or more does not have a detrimental effect?

Comment: The LOH can be compacted "on demand" starting with .net 4.5.1 (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mariohewardt/archive/2013/06/26/no-more-memory-fragmentation-on-the-large-object-heap.aspx)

Comment: @Christian.K So it's not automatic, rather it's per method call. It seems that I'm fine then?

Comment: Yes, but in a multi domain or multi threaded app you cannot be sure when someone requests a compactation. So in general you cannot rely on it not happening.

Comment: Let's keep our eyes on the ball here, this answer does *not* recommend not pinning large arrays.  So this is all rather irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

For your specific use case, it may be worthwhile to use a memory mapped file as the shared memory buffer between your c# and c++ code. This circumvents the garbage collector altogether. And also lets the OS cache pager deal with memory pressure issues, instead of GC managed memory.